# How to access css like : --paper-spinner-layer-1-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500); with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I access css which is written like this(I searched for it but I don't
know how this writing is called):

```
<style>
  paper-spinner{
    --paper-spinner-layer-1-color: var(--paper-green-500);
    --paper-spinner-layer-2-color: var(--paper-green-500);
    --paper-spinner-layer-3-color: var(--paper-green-500);
    --paper-spinner-layer-4-color: var(--paper-green-500);
  }  
</style>
```

with Javascript?

I want to do something like:

```
myPaperSpinner.style.(--paper-spinner etc.).color = red;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those are custom CSS properties for the Polymer spinner. They 're not standard CSS, so you won't be able to use them as such in Javascript.

Your best be would be to read the documentation for the Polymer spinner, which can be found here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-spinner

Comment: I already did, but I can't imagine, that this isn't possible.